# Filtering a dataframe according to user input values in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, input

I need to write a script in python prompting a user to select either the **id is 19876/20807/13978/49999**. Then taking in user input based on up to **id** **column** and **their values**, and returning the respective rows within a dataframe.

For example, if the user want to filter data for 19876, or anything else he must to write these id and the **df2** should contain data only about it.

**Df1**

```
    movie_ref                              year      id
0   Captain America: The First Avenger     1942      nan
0   Avengers: Age of Ultron                2015      nan
0   Avengers: Infinity War                 2017      nan
0   Avengers: Endgame                      2018      nan
```

**Df2**

```
      id         movie_ref                              year
0    19876       Captain America: The First Avenger     1942
0    20807       Avengers: Age of Ultron                2015
0    13978       Avengers: Infinity War                 2017
0    49999       Avengers: Endgame                      2018
```

I have tried to creat something with python and pandas libraries.

```
import pandas as pd


d = {'movie_name': ['Captain America: The First Avenger', 'Avengers: Age of Ultron', 'Avengers: Infinity War', 'Avengers: Endgame'],
 'correct_id': [ 'N/A','N/A','N/A', 'N/A'],'year':[1942,2015,2017,2018]}
d1 = {'movie_ref': ['Captain America: The First Avenger','Avengers: Age of Ultron', 'Avengers: Infinity War', 'Avengers: Endgame'], 
'id': ['19876', '20807','13978','49999'],'year':[1942,2015,2017,2018]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
print(df1)
print(df2)

filter_data = int(input('select movie writing the id: '))

filtered=(df2.loc[df2['id'] == filter_data])
print(filtered)
```

I got as **an output:**

```
select movie writing the id: 49999
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [movie_ref, id, year]
Index: []
```

**expected output**:

```
     movie_ref          id     year
0     Avengers: Endgame  49999  2018
```

Then i want to take the id 49999 and replace the nan in the Df1
**Final output:**

```
  movie_ref                              year        id
0   Captain America: The First Avenger     1942      nan
0   Avengers: Age of Ultron                2015      nan
0   Avengers: Infinity War                 2017      nan
0   Avengers: Endgame                      2018      49999
```

Comment: Have a look at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the edited code, your id column in df2 is a string but you are comparing the input data as int against it. So you have to change it to,

```
filter_data = input('select movie writing the id: ')

filtered=(df2.loc[df2['id'] == filter_data])
print(filtered)

           movie_ref     id  year
3  Avengers: Endgame  49999  2018
```

Now, to replace id, you can do,

```
df1.loc[df1['movie_name'].eq(filtered['movie_ref']), 'correct_id'] = filtered['id']

print(df1)

    movie_name  correct_id  year
0   Captain America: The First Avenger  N/A 1942
1   Avengers: Age of Ultron N/A 2015
2   Avengers: Infinity War  N/A 2017
3   Avengers: Endgame   49999   2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by prompting the user like

```
print(f"Select one of {df['id'].values}")
id = int(input())
```

and then just use e.g. pandas boolean indexing to get the row

```
print(df[df['id'] == id])
```